# HttpURLConnection not sending cookie values to server

Tags: java, android, node.js, cookies, httpurlconnection

I am using HttpURLConnection from android application for connecting rest services via POST method.

it is reaching to my server and after login server is setting some cookie to the response.

but when i am sending further requests then cookie is not going along with those requests.

please tell me the way to do it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you using AndroidHttpClient?

Comment: No i am using HttpURLConnection

Answer (score 1):

You should get the cookies from the login request and then send them as a request parameter in all the subsequent requests. You can set it like this:

```
conn.setRequestProperty("Cookie", YOUR_COOKIES_FROM_LOGIN_REQUEST);
```

You can find a demo [here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Java/URL_Connection_Address/Get_and_set_cookie_through_URLConnection_in_Java.htm).

Comment: But what kind of security is this ? if we have to store cookie separately and send with each request.

Comment: The `HttpUrlConnection` object isn't meant to be reused. So you have to store cookie and send them with each request.

Comment: so is there any way we can reuse connection for POST method , so that no need to send cookie with each request?

Comment: There is, but that's not a really good approach. You could create a `WebView` in your view and make it hidden. `WebView` maintains its sessions and cookies throughout the app. You could post data to a `WebView` and handle response from there.